# RxAndroid to work with ServerSocket - Android

Tags: android, reactive-programming, rx-java, rx-android

I was trying to create Server and Client application using RxAndroid,

Since i am new to Reactive Programming, still i am confused on what Map should be used and how exactly can this be implemented?

This is my current server using Thread:

```
import com.mbh.usbcom.MBLogger.MBLogger;

import java.net.ServerSocket;

/**
 * Created by MBH on 2016-02-01.
 */
public class MBUSBServer {
    interface IRepliedMessageHandler {
        void repliedMessage(String message, int count);
    }

    interface IReceivedMessageHandler {
        void receivedMessage(String message, int count);
    }

    MBLogger logger;

    private static MBUSBServer mInstance = null;
//    private final int PORT = 59900; // anyport
    ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private volatile boolean isRunning = false;
    private final String ReplyMessage = "Client#";

    IRepliedMessageHandler repliedMessageHandler;
    IReceivedMessageHandler receivedMessageHandler;
    Thread mThread;
    int clinetsCount = 0;

    // Singlton : 1 Server at a time
    public static MBUSBServer getInstance() {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new MBUSBServer();
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    private MBUSBServer() {
        logger = new MBLogger.Builder()
                .setTag(MBUSBServer.class)
                .createLogger();
    }

    public void start(IReceivedMessageHandler receivedMessageHandler,
                      IRepliedMessageHandler repliedMessageHandler) {
        this.repliedMessageHandler = repliedMessageHandler;
        this.receivedMessageHandler = receivedMessageHandler;
        start();
    }

    private void start() {
        if (isRunning) return;
        if (mThread != null) {
            mThread = null;
        }

        isRunning = true;
        mThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    logger.logDebug("Initializing ServerSocket");
                    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(59900);
                    serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
                    logger.logDebug("ServerSocker initialized--InetAddress=" + serverSocket.getInetAddress());

                    while (isRunning) {
                        logger.logInfo("ServerSocket is waiting for Client");
                        MBTCPClient mbtcpClient = new MBTCPClient(serverSocket.accept());

                        clinetsCount++;
                        //logger.logDebug("Received Request from Client #" + clinetsCount);

                        // Write rely to socket, then Read from socket, and push message to handler
                        receiveAndReplyWithSocket(false, mbtcpClient, clinetsCount);
                    }

                    isRunning = false;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    isRunning = false;
                    logger.logError(e);
                }
            }
        });
        mThread.start();
    }

    private void receiveAndReplyWithSocket(boolean sameThread, final MBTCPClient mbtcpClient, final int count) {
        if (sameThread) {
            receiveAndReplyWithSocket(mbtcpClient, count);
        } else {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    receiveAndReplyWithSocket(mbtcpClient, count);
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }

    private void receiveAndReplyWithSocket(MBTCPClient mbtcpClient, int count) {
        try {

            final String reply = ReplyMessage + count;
            mbtcpClient.write(reply);
            if (repliedMessageHandler != null) {
                repliedMessageHandler.repliedMessage(reply, count);
            }
            String response = mbtcpClient.read();
            if (receivedMessageHandler != null) {
                receivedMessageHandler.receivedMessage(response, count);
            }
            mbtcpClient.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.logError(e);
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        isRunning = false;
        if (mThread != null) {
            mThread = null;
        }
        if (serverSocket != null) {
            try {
                serverSocket.close();
                serverSocket = null;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        logger.logDebug("Server Has Been Stopped");
    }
}
```

and my current client:

```
import com.mbh.usbcom.MBLogger.MBLogger;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;

/**
 * Created by MBH on 2016-02-02.
 */
public class MBTCPClient {
    Socket socket;
    DataOutputStream out;
    BufferedReader in;
    MBLogger logger = new MBLogger.Builder().setTag(MBTCPClient.class)
            .createLogger();

    public MBTCPClient(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    public MBTCPClient(String hostAdds, int port) {
        try {
            socket = new Socket(hostAdds, port);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.logError(e);
        }
    }

    public String read() {
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            return in.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.logError(e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public boolean write(String reply) {
        if(socket == null) return false;
        try {
            out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            out.writeBytes(reply);
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.logError(e);
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void close() {
        // close socket
        if (socket != null) {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.logError(e);
            }
        }

        // close input stream
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.logError(e);
            }
        }

        // close output stream
        if (out != null) {
            try {
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.logError(e);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think you need rxjava for socket implementation on android. I used one of existing socket libraries and just made all according to MVP (in my case).

Comment: did u check RxNetty? @AndrewF  it looks so sexy :) i would like to use Rx

Comment: true, but we still ned to wait for stable version :)

Comment: @AndrewF  also i need to make my own tcp server not http server